# Stop a process launched using batch file

Tags: java, runtime, game-engine

i launch a batch file from my java code using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start myFile.bat");
```

which in turn launches an application, now i want to stop the application been launched by this batch file, how to achieve it. there may be the case that the same multiple instance of same application are already running, but i want to stop the one being launched by this batch file. is it possible, my server is on windows.

since this was game application and need the enviroment also tried

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
            Process p = rt.exec("C:/Valve/HLServer/hlds.exe +maxplayers 32 -game cstrike -console +port 27015 -nojoy -noipx -heapsize 250000 +map cs_italy +servercfgfile server.cfg +lservercfgfile +mapcyclefile mapcycle.txt +motdfile motd.txt +logsdir logs -zone 2048",null,  new File("C:/Valve/HLServer")) ;
```

but still no luck :(

Comment: what have you done in myFile.bat?

Comment: batch file goes to the desired directory and just launch an exe from the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this will kill the command prompt not the method launched from that command prompt.
```

he is right

do this

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("/folder/exec.exe") //your application
 p.destroy();
```

Comment: this isnt working for my kind of application. it will launch a game HLDS from Steam that has to be launched in console mode and has to pass some parameters to it.

Comment: you can pass parameter as wel, same as u do in batch file

Comment: @varun In that case you could pass parameters like "exec.exe parameter1 parameter2 parameter3"

Comment: tried this but the thing is when i do the same thing on command prompt manually it works fine, but when i do using java code its not executed properly.

Comment: ya tried everything even tried to run with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, parameter, file) command but still not working

Comment: @searock - i am not getting any error the application is getting launched but improperly. i was not pasting the code because it has to do with games and could be bit off topic.

Comment: sorry guys just checked that it worked when executed the new code mentioned in question

Answer (score 2):

[`getRuntime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime%28%29) method returns [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class's object and using the [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object you can call [`destroy()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29) method on the Process object to kill the process

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start myFile.bat"); //starts the process
p.destroy();    //kills the process
```

Comment: this will kill the command prompt not the method launched from that command prompt.

Comment: @varun Well then don't pass `cmd` directly pass the `myFile.bat`

Comment: @Searock- in that case the exe file doesnt gets its enviroment. have to use cmd prompt